# SQL check if the table is exists with dynamic query then return output value

Tags: sql-server-2008

Anyone know why my query not work well

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPMonStoVal]
    @StoDate varchar(25),
    @StockStatus varchar(2) OUT
AS
    DECLARE 
        @TbName varchar(25)

    SET @TbName = 'zSTO:'+@StoDate

    EXEC('IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''[dbo].['+@TbName+']'') AND type in (N''U''))
       SET @StockStatus = ''1''
    ELSE
       SET @StockStatus = ''0'' ')
```

Anyone know why my query not work well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why use Execute text just use simple statement

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SPMonStoVal]
    @StoDate varchar(25),
    @StockStatus varchar(2) OUT
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE 
        @TbName varchar(25)

    SET @TbName = 'zSTO:'+@StoDate

    IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(CAST(@TbName AS NVARCHAR(100))) AND type in (N'U'))
       SET @StockStatus = '1'
    ELSE
       SET @StockStatus = '0'
END
```

Comment: i thought if the table was dynamic so must use execute text.